# Setting a combobox to null on button press, c#. net, mvvm

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, reset

I basically have two comboboxes.  Initially when you enter the screen the two comboboxes are set to null and it works correctly.  The user then makes a selection from the combo boxes and after they press a submit button, the details are moved across to a different screen.  When this submission happens, I effectively want to clear everything so the user can add new values, at the moment the combo box values remain, though they can be changed I would rather they were null for clarity.

I have a reset method where I reset the name to an empty string.  How do I set these combo boxes to null in the reset method?  These are bound to item sources, one to a List, one to a MemberModel.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets here?  I'm not really clear about what's going on.

Comment: You mean set datasource to null?

Answer (score 0):

Combobox1.selectedIndex=-1;